# Justification for axiom OB-RE in deontic logic

Tags: logic, modal-logic, deontology

Let OB p denote "p is obligatory". [Axiom OB-RE](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-deontic/#1.3) is (p ↔ q) → (OB p ↔ OB q). This axiom seems false to me (under the interpretation of obligation). For example, let p denote "don't lie to me" and q denote "hurt me". Suppose p Λ q, that is, you're not lying to me but you *are* hurting me. Then it is true that p ↔ q, since ⊤ ↔ ⊤. Suppose furthermore that OB p, that is, you're obligated not to lie to me. Then OB-RE would imply OB q, that is, *you're obligated to hurt me*. This clearly doesn't seem right. Am I interpreting this axiom incorrectly?

Comment: A theorem in logic means that it can be derived without assumptions. In other words (and given completeness), p ↔ q is a theorem when p ↔ q is a tautology. That doesn't hold in your case.

Comment: See: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Theorem/Logic

Comment: Can someone tell me what the RE here stands for? I came to this question from the Stanford site looking for an answer.

Comment: @weirdalsuperfan Good question. I don't know the answer, but I know that axiom RE exists in other modal logics as well. See [here](http://www.jimpryor.net/teaching/courses/akrasia/modal-survey.html) and [here](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~mjs/teaching/ModalTemporal499/Systems_499_v0809.pdf) (page 4) for instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OB-RE: If p ↔ q is a theorem, then so is OBp ↔ OBq.

In other words, if p and q have the same truth value in each world, and each model, then they're basically the same proposition, and so one is obligatory iff the other is.

This holds in [classical systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_modal_logic) and almost characterizes them. Classical systems correspond to [minimal models](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/modal-logic/minimal-models-for-modal-logics/0CD42FE8ECAEFE19173AF6E7AF18681D), those where what is necessary in a world *x* is just some collection of sets of world. Here a sets of worlds corresponds to a proposition p which holds in exactly those worlds.